# Angular material table not showing values while datasource is populated

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a question about the table provided by the angular material library.

I am trying to populate it with data that i'm getting from a service. I can see that the source that I use for the table is populated, but nothing is shown in html. This is the code I have so far:

```
  public displayedColumns: string[] = ['name', 'saldo', 'totalstripes'];
  public dataSource = new MatTableDataSource;


  constructor(
    private adminservice : AdminService
  ) { 
    this.adminservice.getAllStripesFromAllUsers().subscribe(data => {
      this.dataSource.data = data;
    })

  }
```

.ts file with datasource setting in constructor

```
<mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort>

  <!-- Name Column -->
   <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
     <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Naam </mat-header-cell>
     <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.user_forname}} </mat-cell>
   </ng-container>

  <!-- amount Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="saldo">
     <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Saldo </mat-header-cell>
     <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.user_saldo}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- total stripes Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="totalstripes">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Totaal aantal strepen</mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.totalstripes}}</mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
    <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
</mat-table>
```

The html code for the table.

[datasource that is filled with data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TsITt.png)

Hopefully someone with more knowledge then me can help me out.

p.s this is my first time using stackoverflow, I'm hoping that I have been clear and that this post is according to the guidlines. :)

Comment: try to move the subscription to getAllStripesFromAllUsers() inside the ngOnInit lifecycle hook. It's a bad practice to put some logic inside the constructor.

Comment: Done that, thanks for the tip. Unfortunatly still not working.